# linear algebra, basic questions

Tags: linear-algebra

$ b= (1,1,1),c= (1,2,1) , 0=(0,0,0) , A-matrix$

I need help to prove or disprove the following:

1. If $Ax=b$ has infinite solutions then $Ax=c$ has infinite solutions.
2. if $Ax=b$ has single solution then $Ax=0$ has single solution.

I have been looking at this for an houre and I got no clue what information $Ax=b$ gives me.

Comment: For the first, take $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ as a counterexample.  Then any $x$ whose entries sum to $1$ will have $Ax=b$.  There are of course infinitely many such $x$.  However... since $Ax$ will in this case always have every entry equal (since the range of $A$ is the span of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$), there is no solution to $Ax=c$ (since $c$ is not in the range of $A$)

Comment: How did you conclude from the fact that $Ax=B$ has infinite solutions that $A $has a rank$<3 $?

Comment: @Technically we don't know that $A$ is square, however as $b$ and $c$ are in $\Bbb R^3$, we know there must be three rows in $A$.  That there are infinitely many solutions for $b$ we know that the rref form of $A$ will contain a line of all zeroes, hence there can be at most two pivots and thus rank<3.

Comment: @JMoravitz I still dont understand how you conclude that the rank of A <3 . A rank can be 3 and by solving Ax=b, we will get a line of all zeroes.

Comment: @StavAlfi no you can't.  One of the *many* equivalent interpretations of rank is the number of pivots in the rref form of the matrix, in particular it also equals the number of row pivots.  If there is a row of all zeroes then there is a row without a pivot.  As mentioned, we know the number of rows since it is the same number of rows as $b$.  Since there is at least one row with no pivot, there can be at most two rows with pivots.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer and support. Is there any chance you can explain more on how you came up with your counterexample of A ? I did not get this "(since the range of A is the span of (1,1,1)...". What is a range? (I'm sure my bad english is the cause of this). Agian thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. If $Ax=b$ has infinite solutions then $Ax=c$ has infinite solutions.

If $Ax=b$ has infinite solutions, then the *nullspace* of $A$ is nontrivial.  Easy proof: let $x_1$, $x_2$ be two solutions where $x_1-x_2\ne 0$ then $A(x_1-x_2) = b-b=0$. $\ \ \square$

If the nullspace of $A$ is nontrivial then $Ax=c$ will *either* have infinitely many solutions (if $c$ is in the column space of $A$) or none (otherwise).  JMoravitz provides an example of the latter in the comments.

> 2. if $Ax=b$ has single solution then $Ax=0$ has single solution.

If $Ax=b$ has a single solution, then the nullspace of $A$ is trivial. Easy proof: Assume $y\ne 0$ is in the nullspace of $A$ and $x_1$ is a solution to $Ax=b$. Then $A(x_1+y) = b+0 = b$ so $x_1+y\ne x_1$ is another solution to $Ax=b$.  Contradiction.$\ \ \square$

Then $Ax=$ anything will have a single solution.  Proof: Say $x_1$, $x_2$ are two solutions to $Ax=d$ for some $3\times 1$ matrix $d$ where $x_1\ne x_2$.  Then $A(x_1-x_2) = d-d = 0$.  But then $x_1-x_2\ne 0$ is in the nullspace.  Contradiction.$\ \ \ \square$

Comment: @StavAlfi If you want to prove a statement $A\implies B$ by contradiction, you assume both $A$ and **not** $B$ are true and then show that implies not $A$ is true or $B$ is true.  But a statement can't be true and not true at the same time so that's a contradiction.  In the case of the second proof, I assume $Ax=b$ has a single solution *and* the nullspace of $A$ is nontrivial (meaning there's at least one other solution to $Ax=0$ besides $x=0$) but then I show that that implies that $x_1$ **and** $x_1+y\ne x_1$ are solutions to $Ax=b$.  But $Ax=b$ can't have exactly one solution and two ...

Comment: solutions at once.  So it's a contradiction.

Comment: Okay thank you for the detailed response! In the first proof: Why $Ax=c$ will have infinite many solutions if c is in the column space of $A$ and if not, $Ax=c$ wont have any solutions?

Comment: From the second part, we can see that $Ax=c$ can't have a unique solution so there are only two choices left: no solutions or infinitely many (I assume you already proved in your class that a system of linear equations can only possibly have $0$, $1$, or $\infty$ solutions).  It turns out there are examples of each depending on $A$ (and $c$ but that's fixed in this problem).  JMoravitz gave an example of a possible $A$ where $Ax=c$ has no solutions.  As an instructive exercise, you should try to construct an $A$ where there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately we did not prove that in class. Is there any chance you explain what is the connection between the number of solutions of system of linear equations and the column space of $A$ ?

Comment: Well, it's not so hard: try to prove it yourself.  As for the connection between the column space and solutions, consider $$x_1\pmatrix{a_{11} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n1}} + \cdots + x_m\pmatrix{a_{1m} \\ \vdots \\ a_{nm}} = \pmatrix{a_{11}x_1 + \cdots + a_{1m}x_m \\ \vdots \\ a_{n1}x_1 + \cdots + a_{nm}x_m} = \pmatrix{a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1m} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nm}}\pmatrix{x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_m} = \pmatrix{b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n}$$  This shows that for $b$ to be a solution to $Ax=b$, $b$ must be a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

Comment: Thus there will be at least $1$ solution (though there could be infinitely many) to $Ax=b$ if $b$ is in the column space of $A$ (i.e. it's a linear combination of the columns of $A$).  Likewise, there will be **no** solution if $b$ is *not* in the column space of $A$.

Comment: I could not ask for anything better then that. Thank you so much for your time and your patience  :)